# If a library has a vulnerable function, but my code doesn't call it, is my code at risk? Do I need to update?

Tags: vulnerability, cve, vulnerability-assessment, integer-overflow

I am trying to analyze [CVE-2023-34453](https://nvd.nist.gov/vuln/detail/CVE-2023-34453). As per the NVD description, there is an integer overflow error in snappy-java, specifically in the method `shuffle(int[] input)` in `BitShuffle.java`.

In a huge codeline this CVE was detected, and I want to assess if according to the usage of snappy-java in the codeline, if it is exploitable or not. Searching through the codeline, the guilty method is never used (by never used, I mean I couldn't find a call to this method). Can I base on that and say that there is no way to exploit this CVE in my case?

Comment: Finding ways to call vulnerable functions in unexpected ways is one aspect of exploit development.

Comment: @Brian, so we cannot rule out exploitability if a method is not directly called ? can you elaborate your point or give an example to better understand your point of view?

Comment: that class/method could still be called by other classes/methods in their code without your code explicitly calling it.  Why not just update snappy?  The CVE said it was fixed in 1.1.10.1, and the version up on github is at 1.1.10.5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even if your code doesn't call it, did you check whether any other calls are made to this vulnerable function by components you *do* call? This could be difficult to evaluate in some cases, especially if the code is complex or some kind of indirection is used. Perhaps tracing or using a debugger on the program during normal operation could help confirm that the method is not called.

As @Brian said in the comments, even if the code isn't directly called in your program, an attacker who finds another vulnerability that gives them e.g. a *limited* ability to redirect execution or a *limited* read/write primitive could then try to call the vulnerable function in order to exploit it and gain further control.

However, according to the NVD entry for CVE-2023-34453, it appears the listed impact is limited to denial of service (DoS), so worst case, someone *might* be able to get your code to stop working if they were somehow able to call that function. How you react to this may depend on your threat model, but I would say a hypothetical DoS in a piece of code that isn't likely reachable doesn't seem like too big of a concern.